# How do I get my "calculate button" in a Fragment of a Tabbed Activity working

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an application with three `tabs` and three `fragments` created for the three tabs which represent a bmi calculator a length converter and weight converter. non of the calculate buttons work in any of the fragments

Ive tried setting `onclick` from the `xml` and also overriding the `onclick` method in `fragment.java` file

```
@Override


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1, container, false);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    height = height.findViewById(R.id.height);
    weight = weight.findViewById(R.id.weight);
    result = result.findViewById(R.id.result);

    calc = calc.findViewById(R.id.calc);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String heightStr = height.getText().toString();
            String weightStr = weight.getText().toString();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
                // e.g. launch a new activity
     if (Objects.equals(heightStr, "") || !Objects.equals(weightStr, "")) {
                    float heightValue = Float.parseFloat(heightStr);
                    float weightValue = Float.parseFloat(weightStr);
                    float bmi = weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);

                    displayBMI(bmi);
                } else {
                    result.setText(getString(R.string.Enter_height));


                }

            }


            private void displayBMI(float bmi) {


                String bmiLabel;


      if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) <= 0) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.severely_underweight);
  } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 16f) <= 0) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_underweight);
} else if (Float.compare(bmi, 16f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) <= 0) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.underweight);
} else if (Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 25f) <= 0) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.normal_weight);
  } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 25f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 30f) <= 0) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.over_weight);
  } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 30f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 35f) <= 0) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.first_class_obese);
  } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 35f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 40f) <= 0) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.second_class_obese);
                } else {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.third_class_obese);
                }

                bmiLabel = bmi + "\n" + bmiLabel;
                result.setText(bmiLabel);

            }
        })

        ;
    }
```

I expect the bmi to be calculated when the `button: "@id calc"` is clicked from the values put in the `editText` field for `height` and `weight`

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: the button does nothing when clicked

Comment: try adding some logs so you can know if the code inside onclick is getting executed or not.

Comment: thank you..please I'm not very familiar adding logs..it would be fine if you help me through

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors. I have fixed them while I did not change your code's logic.

Since details provided by you aren't enough, I will have to assume a few things here,

- Variable `result` variable is of type `TextView` in your Fragment's XML file and has the id as `result`.
- Variables `height`, `weight` is of type `EditText` in your Fragment's XML file (as you have mentioned) and have id as `height` and `weight`.
- Variable `calc` is of type `Button` in your Fragment's XML file and has the id as `calc`.
- What is `Objects` in your application? I cannot see its declaration or where is it initialized. Unless we know what it is, without initializing this code won't work

  ```
  String heightStr;
  String weightStr;

  EditText height;
  EditText weight;
  TextView result;

  Button calc;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
  savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1, container, false);

      height = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.height);
      weight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.weight);

      result = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result);

      calc = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calc);

      calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
              // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
              // e.g. launch a new activity

              heightStr = height.getText().toString();
              weightStr = weight.getText().toString();

              if (Objects.equals(heightStr, "") || !Objects.equals(weightStr, "")) {
                  float heightValue = Float.parseFloat(heightStr);
                  float weightValue = Float.parseFloat(weightStr);
                  float bmi = weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);
                  displayBMI(bmi);
              } else {
                  result.setText(getString(R.string.Enter_height));
              }
          }
      });
      return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }


  private void displayBMI(float bmi) {

      String bmiLabel;

      if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) <= 0) {
          bmiLabel = getString(R.string.severely_underweight);
      } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 15f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 16f) <= 0) {
          bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_underweight);
      } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 16f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) <= 0) {
          bmiLabel = getString(R.string.underweight);
      } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 18.5f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 25f) <= 0) {
          bmiLabel = getString(R.string.normal_weight);
      } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 25f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 30f) <= 0) {
          bmiLabel = getString(R.string.over_weight);
      } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 30f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 35f) <= 0) {
          bmiLabel = getString(R.string.first_class_obese);
      } else if (Float.compare(bmi, 35f) > 0 && Float.compare(bmi, 40f) <= 0) {
          bmiLabel = getString(R.string.second_class_obese);
      } else {
          bmiLabel = getString(R.string.third_class_obese);
      }

      bmiLabel = bmi + "\n" + bmiLabel;
      result.setText(bmiLabel);

  }
  ```

Comment: thank you I added this line:  height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height); then it gives error:cannot resolve method findViewById(int)..I had to add method qualifier which is the id before  findViewById(R.id.height); I had to remove EditText from here because it shows cast to be redundant.     height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);      this block of code heightStr = height.getText();
 weightStr = weight.getText(); shows incompatible types.
Required:
java.lang.String
Found:
android.text.Editable.  please more help needed

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it. use `heightStr = height.getText().toString();` and `weightStr = weight.getText().toString();`

cast is redundant simply means it isn't required.

Also I don't know if method qualifier was necesarry, been a long time since I used EditText and as far as I remember I never needed it, will have to check for it again.

Comment: thank you ..I have used your correction but the button still dosen't work.  please more solutions if you have

Comment: It wouldn't work. What is `Objects` in your code??? It does not seem to be initialized nor can I see the line where some value is assigned to it. How can you compare to a null value?? Also what is `result`?? Is it a `TextView` or something else?

Comment: I have edited the code and removed that line from the code and it still does not work. result is a TextView for output

Comment: what did you replace that line with?? You need to have a valid comparision for it to work.

Comment: I removed the if else statement. the second fragment also has a button and it dosen't  work too

Comment: Actually, I just realized that you are using fragments (sorry for my complete ignorance). You can't initialize variables in fragments the way you did in Activities. It's a bit different for fragments.

I have edited the code. The code which you had written in `onCreate()`, I have added it in `onCreateView()`. For using `findViewById`, you will have to initialize `View` variable first and then find component's id from the `View`'s variable (if that makes any sense) I have updated the code so you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

try adding onClick method in Xml on button click.

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
```

Inside your fragment create the same method as you mentioned in your XML.

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){
    //add your code here.
}
```

Comment: thank you ..would I need to add onclicklistener and override onClick method inside this method     public void onButtonClick(View){
    //add your code here.
}

Comment: no if you are doing it in the xml you dont need to add click listener.please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: it shows error message variable "onButtonClick" never used

Comment: onButtonClick should be a function,why its showing variable to you.

Comment: maybe because its in a fragment...the buttons in the other fragments are not working ..all do a calculate function